# In echarts.js, line chart, how to make xAxis show months when I only have the data of every date?

Tags: echarts

In line charts, I want to show month names on xAxis and every month shows its data by date.

I've tried multi xAxis and it's not working well, or maybe use formatter?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the axisLable formatter? You can call a function there to do the formatting.

```js
xAxis: {
          axisLabel: {
                        formatter: (function(value){
                            return moment(value).format('MMM-YY');
                        })
                    }
                   
       }
```

Hope this will help.